# Can CMRR of a data acquisition input be measured this way?

Tags: measurement, cmrr

I want to check a data acquisition input or overall CMRR of a signal chain roughly by a simple method.

Normally for a daq input CMRR is defined as:

CMRR = 20×log10(Vin/Vout)

where Vin is the common mode voltage Vcm applied at both inputs.

But in practice I hesitate to use the above formula.
It is because when I short the inputs together the Vout is not zero. It has some offset with standard deviation.

So first I short the inputs I obtain **x** at the output. x represents output voltage and xrms is the rms value of x.

Then I apply purse sinusoid common mode voltage by a function generator. I call the rms value of common mode input as Vrms and the output as **a**.

Finally I double the pure sinusoid input common mode voltage as 2Vrms and I call the output as **b**.

I tried to illustrate these by the following drawing:

[image]

Is the following approach to estimate the CMRR mathematically correct?:

CMRR = 20xlog10(ΔVcm_rms/ΔVout_rms)

ΔVcm = 2Vrms - Vrms = Vrms

ΔVout_rms = (a_rms - x_rms) - (b_rms - x_rms)

CMRR = 20xlog10[V_rms / (a_rms - b_rms)]

Is the above a valid estimation to verify the claimed CMRR?

Comment: Just a note on the first configuration, " when I short the inputs together the Vout is not zero".  It's most likely due to Vos, the input voltage offset of that particular opamp.

Comment: Its not an opamp maybe an inAmp since it is about a data acquistion board input. Drawing is just to illustrate the connections.

Comment: Instrumentation amp is just a special configuration of opamp(s), sometimes made discreetly sometimes integrated into a single chip.  Either way, they all still have a Vos, check the datasheet.

Comment: It is a board input https://www.mccdaq.com/PDFs/specs/USB-1608G-Series-data.pdf

Answer (score 1):

CMRR not just the Common Mode gain, ***Acm*** but the rejection ratio of CM gain to DM gain.

Input \$V_{{IN}_{cm}}=\dfrac{V_{in-} + V_{in+}}{2}   \$

\$A_{cm}=\dfrac{V_{{OUT}_{cm}}}{V_{{IN}_{cm}}}   \$   , cm = common mode
\$A_{dm}=\dfrac{V_{{OUT}_{dm}}}{V_{{IN}_{dm}}}   \$    , dm =  diff. mode

\$CMRR=\dfrac{A_{cm}}{A_{dm}}   \$

By nulling input offset to get 0V out, then you can apply Acm input and divide by open loop gain.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fKMAS4.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The grounded clock + sine must be within the CM input range.
Then if you have a DAC compare output SINE with input SINE and adjust ratios of Vdm/Vcm until you can see results.   Or you can sweep Vdm instead of a pulse just as long as it is not harmonically related to SINE Vdm .

There may be better ways of analyzing CMRR results with a Spectrum Analyzer or a WAV file on Audacity.exe

Comment: It is a board I cannot  do nulling https://www.mccdaq.com/PDFs/specs/USB-1608G-Series-data.pdf

Comment: I can just apply inputs and obtain outputs yet Im looking for an okay method

Comment: You can on the 8x2 mode fIN = 60 Hz, all input ranges: 86 dB.   But I suggest if you have a CM problem , look elsewhere. Balance error on {source Z, cable impedance vs f, load, loop area, CM noise level etc}

Comment: i dont have a problem I just want to measure myself CMRR of the board.

Comment: OK If you have a DAC on-board generate a triangle test pattern to calibrate it then use it to show results.

Comment: I dont understand what u mean

Comment: I need a clear Do this do that style of step by step method

Comment: Do you have the DAC option?

Comment: I have function gen and a seperate Dac as well

Comment: What is 220 Ohm for?

Comment: Typical cable impedance for noise ingress.  Optional

Answer (score 0):

A better way to measure CMRR is with a circuit like this:

[image]

> The common-mode rejection ratio (CMRR) of an op amp is the ratio of
>   apparent change of offset resulting from a change of common-mode
>   voltage to the applied change of common-mode voltage. It is often of
>   the order of 80 dB to 120 dB at dc, but lower at higher frequencies.
>
> The test circuit is ideally suited to measuring CMRR (Figure 6). The
>   common-mode voltage is not applied to the DUT input terminals, where
>   low-level effects would be likely to disrupt the measurement, but the
>   power-supply voltages are altered (in the same—i.e., common—direction,
>   relative to the input), while the remainder of the circuit is left
>   undisturbed.
>
> In the circuit of Figure 6, the offset is measured at TP1 with
>   supplies of ±V (in the example, +2.5 V and –2.5 V) and again with both
>   supplies moved up by +1 V to +3.5 V and –1.5 V). The change of offset
>   corresponds to a change of common mode of 1 V, so the dc CMRR is the
>   ratio of the offset change and 1 V.
>   Source: https://www.analog.com/en/analog-dialogue/articles/simple-op-amp-measurements.html

### EDIT

Now that you mention an ADC, it's a bit different.

$$ CMRR = \frac{A_{Diff}}{A_{CM}}$$

where

$$A_{Diff}= \frac{\Delta Output Code}{\Delta Differential Voltage}$$
$$A_{CM}= \frac{\Delta Output Code}{\Delta Common Mode Voltage}$$

Source: m.eet.com/media/1175625/c1022edited.pdf

So one way this could be tested is by fixing the differential voltage on one side of the ADC with a voltage source (like an isolated power supply with low noise for V1  if you have a really nice one at hand, a battery with a voltage divider might work also) and then vary the common mode voltage. Ideally the output code shouldn't change.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8Gimk.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93121/discussion-on-answer-by-laptop2d-can-cmrr-of-a-data-acquisition-input-be-measure).  Any conclusions reached should be edited back into the question and/or any answer(s).